# Qualtrics: Is there a good way to call these embedded data field?

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

This is a question on a Qualtrics survey.

I have embedded data fields with following names `cand_1_name` and `cand_2_name` etc. In repeated questions using Loop and Merge, I want to pipe different fields in each round. For example, in the first round, pipe `cand_1_name` and then in the second round pipe `cand_2_name`, and so on.

Is there a good way to implement this? My Qualtrics account is with javascript turned on.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the problem by myself. Here is what I did. I set different Embedded Field Name as a loop and merge field value. It worked perfectly. Here is the screenshot of what I set.

[image]

Comment: This is definitely the best way to do this